# Least number coprime to a given integer

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

For a positive integer $n$ let $$f(n):=\min\{m\in \mathbb N: m>1, \gcd(m,n)=1\} .$$
Equivalently, $f(n) $ is the smallest prime not dividing $n$.
Is there any upper bound literature for this? It is not difficult to prove that $$ \#\{1<m\leq x: \gcd(m,n)=1 \} \geq \frac{\phi(n) }{n } x-1-2^{\omega(n) }, $$ hence, $$f(n) \leq 2 + 2^{\omega(n) }\frac{n }{\phi(n) }\leq 2+ 4^{\omega(n ) } .$$
If $n=\prod_{p\leq t}p$ then $f(n) \asymp t \asymp \omega(n) \log \omega(n)$, so perhaps something polynomial in $\omega(n)$ might be achievable for general $n$.
Is it possible to improve this as function of $\omega$? PS. I do not care about bounds without $\omega$, since these are easy. For example, all primes $p<f(n)$ must divide $n$ hence $$ \prod_{p<f(n) } p \leq n \Rightarrow f(n) \ll \log n.$$

Comment: I guess that $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. If $f(n)=p_{m+1}$ is the $(m+1)$-th prime, then $n$ must be divisible by $p_1\cdots p_m$, hence $f(n) \ll m \log m \ll \omega(n) \log \omega(n)$. Your example shows one cannot hope for a better bound.

Comment: While I am not sure if this helps but bounds on average of $f(n)$ have been proven in corollary 3 here. https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2508

Comment: @François Brunault: thanks, this is exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n)$ be the least prime not dividing $n$.  If $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime, $m\geq 1$ is an integer, and $$q_m = \prod_{k=1}^m p_k,$$ then $f(q_m)=p_{m+1}$.  Indeed, $q_m$ is the least positive integer at which $f$ equals $p_{m+1}$, so we find that $f$ is maximized along the sequence of primorials $q_m$.

By the prime number theorem, we have $$q_m = e^{(1+o(1))m\log m},\qquad p_{m+1}=(1+o(1))m\log m.$$  Thus, $$f(e^{(1+o(1))m\log m})=(1+o(1))m\log m.$$  Inverting this relationship, we find that $$f(n) = (1+o(1))\log n$$ when $n$ is a primorial.  Since $f$ is maximized along the primorials, we find that $$f(n)\leq (1+o(1))\log n$$ for all $n\geq 2$.  Using explicit forms of the prime number theorem, one could bound the $o(1)$ term completely explicitly.

Comment: not sure why you repeated parts of the first post to be honest.

Comment: @Dr.Pi for the sake of having a self-contained answer.